# General solution of $a^x = b^x\cdot(1-c) - c$

Tags: economics, transcendental-equations

I am doing some simple models to estimate the cost of having unrealized taxed investments, but I keep running into equations that have the form of:

$$a^x = b^x\cdot(1-c) - c$$

Or even,

$$a^x = b^x\cdot d - c$$

All of the 'numbers' in the equations are in $(0,\infty)$.

From my understanding, these equations fall into the category of transcendental equations.
I have no idea of to proceed to solve the above equations.
I am not looking just for the solution to the equations, but also want to understand how to solve them, in case I get similar trouble in the future.

Comment: You can try and provide info about each variable (maybe constant) in your equation, for example $c$ might be a rational non integer number, and then some algebraic operations might be made to find easy ways to solve this and so on...

Comment: This equation cannot be solved algebraically. So you have to use a numerical method.

Comment: @callculus And still numerical method will solve or at least approximate this

Comment: This can be transformed into a general trinomial: $x^r+ax+b=0$. This site has solutions to such equations

Answer (score 1):

A transcendental equation contains a [transcendental function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function) that cannot be expressed in finite number of simple algebraic operations, and also such equation has no [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), has no finite number of standard operations.

You can express the equation through a function $f$ and then use some simple calculus methods to at least approximate $x$

$$f(x)=b^x\cdot d - c - a^x \quad f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{30px} \text{$a,b,c,d$ are also in the domain}$$

$$f(0)=d-c-1\hspace{30px} d\geq1+c \quad \text{or} \quad d< 1+c \\ \text{When $d=1+c$ you have $f(0)=0$}$$

$$f'(x)=d\ln{b}\cdot b^x-\ln{a}\cdot a^x \\[6px] f'(x)=0\implies a^x=d\frac{\ln{b}}{\ln{a}}b^x\\[6px]x=\log_a{d}+\log_a{\ln b}+x\cdot\log_a{b}-\log_a{\ln a}\\[6px] x=m=\frac{\log_a{d}+\log_a{\ln b}-\log_a{\ln a}}{1-\log_a{b}} \\[20px] \text{There exists only one $m$ for which the function is min or max} \\ \text{This is used for the following...}$$

You can then set $f$ to be defined by, $f(x) = d\cdot b^x -a^x$
And $g(x)=d\cdot b^x -c -a^x$

then, $f(n) = 0 \implies a^n=d\cdot b^n \implies n=\log_a{d} + n\log_a{b} \implies n=\frac{\log_a{d}}{1-\log_a{b}}$

If you think about the graph of the functions, the area between $f$ and $\frac{c-0}{t_0-n}(x-n)$ and interval $[t_0, n]$ is useful in the following

Where the second function is the line that goes through point $x:f(x)=0$, (that is point $(n, 0)$) and point $(t_0, f(n) + c)=(t_0, c)$, where $t_0: g(t_0)=0$

So $$\int_{t_0}^n f(x)-c\frac{(x-n)}{t_0-n}dx \approx 0$$

But the bigger $c$ gets, the less approximate it gets, though as $c \rightarrow 0$ both sides are equal.